# Have a ragged array print vertically?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to print an array of set values, and i can have it print horizontally, but i want the column results to be vertical. How would i do that?
code:

```
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double nums1[][] ={{1, 2, 3}, 
                       {4, 5, 6}, 
                       {7, 8, 9}
    };

    printHoriz(nums1);
}
public static void printHoriz(double[][] nums) {        
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Col " + (i + 1) + "    ");
      for (int j = 0; j < nums[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(nums[i][j] + "    ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    } 
  }
```

}

results

```
Col 1    1.0    2.0    3.0
Col 2    4.0    5.0    6.0
Col 3    7.0    8.0    9.0
```

desired results

```
3.00      6.00      9.00
2.00      5.00      8.00
1.00      4.00      7.00
Col 1     Col 2     Col 3
```

Comment: `for (int i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { for (int j = 0; j < nums[i].length; j++) { ... } }`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp This causes the last column to be printed first, so i get `Col 3    7.0    8.0    9.0
Col 2    4.0    5.0    6.0
Col 1    1.0    2.0    3.0` but its still not printing vertically.  Doing for `(int j = nums[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--)` does reverse the order, so its a step in the right direction

Comment: Forgot to mention: inside the loop `System.out.print(nums[j][i] + "    ");` Note: `i` and `j` reversed.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp that seemed to get them vertical, the only other thing would to get the `Col 1    Col 2    Col 3` underneath each column. Would i add an output to the loop somewhere to have it output at the bottom of each column?

Comment: Make another loop to print the labels after the main loop.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp realized that after i posted the comment, works now. Thanks!